# Efficient way to preserve object type after a slicing operation

Tags: python, performance, oop, casting, slice

I'm looking for a fast, clean and pythonic way of slicing custom made objects while preserving their type after the operation.

To give you some context, I have to deal with a lot of semi-unstructured data and handle it I work with lists of dictionaries. To streamline some operations I have created an "ld" object, that inherits from "list". Amongst its many capabilities it checks that the data was provided on the correct format. Let's simplify it by saying it ensures that all entries of the list are dictionaries containing some key "a", as shown bellow:

```
class ld( list):
     def __init__(self, x):
          list.__init__(self, x)
          self.__init_check()

     def __init_check(self):
          for record in self:
               if isinstance( record, dict) and "a" in record:
                    pass
               else:
                     raise TypeError("not all entries are dictionaries or have the key 'a'")
          return
```

This behaves correctly when the data is as desired and initialises ld:

```
tt = ld( [{"a": 1, "b":2}, {"a":4}, {"a":6, "c":67}])
type( tt)
```

It is also does the right thing when the data is incorrect:

```
ld( [{"w":1}])
ld( [1,2,3])
```

However the problems comes when I proceed to slice the object:

```
type( tt[:2])
```

tt[:2] is a list and no longer as all the methods and attributes that I created in the full-fledged ld object. I could reconvert the slice into an ld but that means that it would have to go through the entire initial data checking process again, slowing down computations a lot.

Here is the solution I came up with to speed things up:

```
class ld( list):
    def __init__(self, x, safe=True):
        list.__init__(self, x)
        self.__init_check( safe)

    def __init_check(self, is_safe):
        if not is_safe:
            return
        for record in self:
            if isinstance( record, dict) and "a" in record:
                pass
            else:
                raise TypeError("not all entries are dictionaries or have the key 'a'")
        return

    def __getslice__(self, i, j):
        return ld( list.__getslice__( self, i, j), safe=False)
```

Is there a cleaner and more pythonic way of going about it?
Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think subclassing `list` to verify the shape or type of its contents in general is the right approach. The `list` pointedly doesn't care about its contents, and implementing a class whose constructor behavior varies based on flags passed to it is messy. If you need a constructor that verifies inputs, just do your check logic in a function that returns a list.

```
def make_verified_list(items):
    """
    :type items: list[object]
    :rtype: list[dict]
    """
    new_list = []
    for item in items:
        if not verify_item(item):
             raise InvalidItemError(item)
        new_list.append(item)
    return new_list

def verify_item(item):
    """
    :type item: object
    :rtype: bool
    """
    return isinstance(item, dict) and "a" in item
```

Take this approach and you won't find yourself struggling with the behavior of core data structures.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but the object does multiple tasks that were not relevant for the question, so I skipped them. The core of the problem to me is maintaining the object type.